# Visualforce in the sidebar

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

I have a created a custom home page component and it will be displaying the following VF page.

The issue here is after adding the home page component to my home page layout I am unable to see the VF page rendering.

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="CasesSideBarController">
<html>
<head>
   <style>
            body
            {
              background-color: #CEED7;
              font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
              font-size:12px;

            }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<apex:dataTable value="{!casecountbystatus}" var="c">
<apex:column >
<apex:outputText style="font-weight:bold" value="{!c}" />
</apex:column>
<tr />
<apex:column >
<apex:outputtext style="padding-left:10px" value="{!casecountbystatus[c]}" />
</apex:column>


</apex:dataTable>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class CasesSideBarController {

public Map<String,Integer> casecountbystatus {get;set;}

public CasesSideBarController()
{

List<String> closedLables = new List<String>();
for(CaseStatus ca : [Select MasterLabel FROM CaseStatus WHERE IsClosed = true])
{
closedLables.add(ca.MasterLabel);
}

casecountbystatus = new Map<String,Integer>();
for(AggregateResult ar : [SELECT Status, COUNT(Id) CaseCount FROM Case WHERE Status NOT IN :closedLables GROUP BY Status])
{

casecountbystatus.put((String) ar.get('Status'), (Integer) ar.get('CaseCount'));

}


}

}
```

Screenshot of the home page layout shown below :

[image]

Instead it is showing the VF page code.

Can someone tell me why the VF page is not getting rendered and only the actual VF markup is getting rendered ?

Comment: Do you have Development Mode enabled for your User? Looks like a development frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable development mode and check it may solve

Comment: Welcome to SFSE raviteja. Can you add some extra content to this to say how to do that and why it works? You're 100% right, just good to have more details available to users :)